# How to implement Foreach in my class so I can get each key name and value?

Tags: c#, foreach

```
public class Zone
{
    public string zoneID { get; set; }
    public string zoneName { get; set; }
    public string zonePID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use foreach for Zone, like

```
var zone = new Zone(){zoneId = "001", zoneName = "test"};
foreach(var field in zone)
{
   string filedName = field.Key;  //for example : "zoneId"
   string filedValue = filed.value; //for example : "001"
}
```

I just don't konw how to implement `GetEnumerator()` in Zone class

Comment: To get a good answer, you should probably explain what it is you are actually trying to accomplish. You could implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` without too much trouble (using reflection), but I'm skeptical that would be a _good_ way of solving whatever your bigger problem is. One common alternative would be for your class to use a dictionary to maintain the field names and values, and then enumerating those is trivial (since that's exactly what a dictionary produces when enumerated). But there's not enough information in the question to know what the right answer is.

Comment: This is definitely an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), that is, you think this solution *A* should solve some problem *B* but instead of asking us to help you with *B* you're asking us to help you with the solution that doesn't work *A*.

Answer (score 4):

You can't enumerate the **properties** of a class (in a simple way)

Use a string array or string list or a dictionary inside your class.

Note: Indeed it is possible to enumerate the properties of a class using Reflection, but this is not the way to go in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var field in zone)
{
   string filedName = field.zoneID;  //Id of property from Zone Class
   string filedValue = filed.zoneName ; //name of property from Zone Class
}
```

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could equip `Zone` with this method:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> AsDictionary()
{
  return new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      { "zoneID", zoneID },
      { "zoneName", zoneName },
      { "zonePid", zonePid },
    };
 }
```

Then you can `foreach` that.

Alternatively, you can implement `GetEnumerator()` as an iterator block where you `yield return` the three `new KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

I am not saying that this design is particularly recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks eveyrone! It Seems I need to use reflection to achieve the goal.

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] pis = zone.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in pis)
{
    if (prop.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string))) 
    {
        string key = prop.Name;
        string value = (string)prop.GetValue(zome, null);
        dict.Add(key, value); //the type of dict is Dictionary<str,str>
    }
}
```

Just don't know wheather this is a good solution.